# Unable to load dynamic library in watchKit 2.0 with cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, watchkit, swift2, xcode7-beta4

I am unable to successfully run a WatchKit app using my installed CocoaPods and am getting a "dyld: Library not loaded...Reason: image not found" error.

The environment is as follows: Swift 2.0, WatchKit 2.0, CocoaPods 0.38.2, Xcode 7 Beta 4 with a Project using some internal CocoaPods I developed for an iPhone app with a WatchKit extension.

I have built a number of internally used CocoaPods that contain common code I would like to invoke from both my main app and the WatchKit extension. Below is the Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'http://<local-git>/podspecs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'Destinations511' do
  platform :ios, '9.0'

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'APIKit', :path => '~/Documents/Libraries/APIKit'
  pod 'DestinationsKit', :path => '~/Documents/Libraries/DestinationsKit'
end

target 'Destinations511 WatchKit Extension' do
   platform :watchos, '2.0'

   pod 'APIKit', :path => '~/Documents/Libraries/APIKit'
   pod 'DestinationsKit', :path => '~/Documents/Libraries/DestinationsKit'
end
```

I can build my main app and it runs as expected. I can compile the watch kit app, but when it runs, I get the following:

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/APIKit.framework/APIKit Referenced from (...) Reason: image not found.
```

I have tried solutions mentioned for other dylib problems including:

- ensured my Target->Build Settings->Runpath Search Paths includes @executable_path/Frameworks
- tried adding APIKit.framework to Target->General->Embedded Binaries (which for some reason won't even add the framework when I select it)
- deintegrated by Podfile and rebuilt it.
- Added APIKit.framework to the Target->General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries

When I look at my Pods directory in Xcode, I see two instances of each Framework (which I assume is because there is one for the app and one for the watch). All of them stay red even when I have successfully built and am running the iPhone app.

Likely related, but not sure how to solve, is that I get a number of warnings when I compile (regardless of target) along the lines of:

```
 ld: warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions: /Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dlixiemzyqyquocjthlseirhdxcm/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Pods_MyProject_WatchKit_Extension.framework/Pods_MyProject_WatchKit_Extension
```

In the effort to be complete, here is the PodSpec for APIKit

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "APIKit"
  s.version      = "1.1"
  s.summary      = "APIKit provides the basic classes and methods common to a number of our apps"

  s.homepage     = "http://.../apikit.git"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.author             = { "me" => "me@me.com" }

  s.platform     = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = "9.0"
  s.watchos.deployment_target = "2.0"

   s.source       = { :git => "http://my-git-location/apikit.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }

  s.source_files  = "APIKit"

  s.frameworks = "UIKIt", "CoreLocation"

  s.requires_arc = true

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little counterintuitive, and results in a warning from CocoaPods when you install/update pods, but I fixed this problem by setting `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` to `NO` in the WatchKit Extension’s build settings, even though it contained Swift. The app still runs, and it’s in the App Store, but CocoaPods still warns me about this setting.